# How did the Astronomical model of Sacrobosco differ from Ptolemy's?

Tags: astronomy, islamic-science, ptolemy

According to Wikipedia, Sacrobosco's De Sphaera described the Ptolemaic system, but drew on additional ideas from Islamic Astronomy. How did Sacrobosco's model differ from that of Ptolemy?

Comment: "Sacrobosco's model" is an overstatement. It was a loose redux of Ptolemy with many details glossed over, and amateur errors, especially concerning the lunar motion, see [Barker](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-30833-9_6). There was a whole industry of *sphaera* treatises in the middle ages, some of which did incorporate Arabic innovations, but Sacrobosco's was not one of them. Grosseteste used ibn Qurra's device to explain lunar trepidation, for example, see [Mahoney](https://www.princeton.edu/~hos/mike/texts/ptolemy/ptolemy.html).